# PostgreSQL 9.0 error: column t.tgisconstraint does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

When trying to add a new table with some columns I get this error when trying to save it. I received this error on two different computers with version 9.0. Any ideas why this is happening? I get the error with the Navicat IDE as well as PGAdmin.

Comment: Post the statement you're trying to use.

Comment: Its through the GUI when trying to create a table with a column. When i and alter the table through design view I get the same error as well.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your GUI. Use SQL to create and alter tables, problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need pgAdmin version 1.12 (or later, but there is no later available ATM) to work with PostgreSQL 9.0. The error indicates you're using a previous version.

Getting the same error in Navicat just says that it is also not compatible with PostgreSQL 9.0. You need to upgrade to a version that is. Can't give you version numbers there, don't know anything about Navicat.

Answer (score 2):

`tgisconstraint` is not a column in `pg_trigger` anymore as of `9.0`.

What client are you using?