# Error accessing column metadata on Spring MVC + Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am configuring my Spring MVC project with deploying on Tomcat Local Server (tomcat 9) on Intellij Idea.Please look at the code and help me identify what I am missing. 
I can not find any mistakes in the code.

First class House

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "house")
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "houseid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long houseid;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "housetype")
    private String housetype;

    @Column(name = "personid")
    private Long personid;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "personid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Person owner;
--getters & setters --
}
```

Second class Person

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
@Column(name = "personid", unique = true)
private Long personid;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "patronymic")
private String patronymic;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<House> houses;

public List<House> getHouses() {
    return houses;
}

public void setHouses(List<House> houses) {
    this.houses = houses;
}
--getters & setters --
}
```

application:properties

```
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
db.username=postgres
db.password=test
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Config class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("BeNi")
@EnableJpaRepositories("BeNi.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBN2DDL_SQL = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

@Resource private Environment environment;

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("BeNi");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory();
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}

@Bean
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}

private DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() throws Exception {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "BeNi" });
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    Properties jproperties = new Properties();
    jproperties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    jproperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
    jproperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jproperties);
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

}

[My tables looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8UlW.png)

So I have a problem. Application know about these tables, but show an error on table house. (Without this table all is OK, only this table is "broken" and i dont know why)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectId</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Javax -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Error trace :

```
    Connected to server
[2019-01-21 02:59:29,102] Artifact projectId:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
21-Jan-2019 14:59:30.819 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 89ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
21-Jan-2019 14:59:31.770 WARN [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.logDeprecation HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
21-Jan-2019 14:59:31.784 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
21-Jan-2019 14:59:31.942 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
21-Jan-2019 14:59:31.945 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
21-Jan-2019 14:59:31.948 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
21-Jan-2019 14:59:32.027 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
21-Jan-2019 14:59:32.332 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
21-Jan-2019 14:59:32.555 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
21-Jan-2019 14:59:32.559 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@6ab47c80
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.351 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.393 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.448 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.463 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.571 WARN [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.571 ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions ОШИБКА: столбец t1.tgconstrname не существует
  Позиция: 113
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#cfd5926' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#cfd5926': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in BeNi.config.WebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: house
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#cfd5926' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#cfd5926': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in BeNi.config.WebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: house
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#cf5926' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#cfd5926': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in BeNi.config.WebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: house
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#cfd5926': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in BeNi.config.WebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: house
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in BeNi.config.WebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: house
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: house
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: house
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at BeNi.config.WebConfig.entityManagerFactory(WebConfig.java:50)
    at BeNi.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1b766e6.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$1(<generated>)
    at BeNi.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1b766e6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1f0ba2b4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at BeNi.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1b766e6.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: house
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:679)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.foreignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getForeignKey(TableInformationImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.findMatchingForeignKey(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: столбец t1.tgconstrname не существует
  Позиция: 113
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getImportedExportedKeys(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:3477)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:3670)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:628)
    ... 118 more
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.600 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.681 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/projectId_war] startup failed due to previous errors
21-Jan-2019 14:59:33.706 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [projectId_war] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2019-01-21 02:59:33,718] Artifact projectId:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
21-Jan-2019 14:59:39.075 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\manager]
21-Jan-2019 14:59:39.173 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [97] ms
```

Comment: The driver version `9.1-901-1.jdbc4` is hopelessly outdated. Use the current one, and see if that error still occurs

Comment: Problem is not in driver

Comment: How do you know that? That outdated driver will not properly work with any supported Postgres version. Especially when it comes to "metadata" access the driver version must be compatible with the database version.

Comment: It cant be a problem in driver because it works if i delete part with "House". Connection is OK

Comment: You use rather unusual package naming scheme. Might be that the `House` table lies outside of the scanning scope of `@ComponentScan("BeNi")`?

Comment: Do you have a public no-arg constructor in `House`? Clearly, something "не существует".

Comment: The root of problem is trying to make @OneToMany same way like on Spring boot. Solved, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: столбец t1.tgconstrname не существует
  Позиция: 113`

The columnn tgconstrname does not exist in table.

... which sounds like a "driver conflict" (< 9.0) (see: [PostgreSQL 9.0 error: column t.tgisconstraint does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4157316/592355), esp. [Quassnoi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157537/592355))

And [this (comment)](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3135?focusedCommentId=43542&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-43542) sounds helpful & quite up-to date.